# как сделать коммит из локальной ветки в удалённую, если такой ветки в удалённом репозитории нет?

Tags: git, gitlab

я сделал git clone репозитория и создал локальную ветку, сделал в ней свои изменения и сделал коммит, и хочу запушить их в такую же ветку в удалённом репозитории, но такой ветки там нет.
git push мне пишет

```
`fatal: The current branch nojira_fix_telegram_bot has no upstream branch.`
```

Может кто то знает как исправить данную проблему?

Comment: Ответ
_git push origin nojira_fix_telegram_bot_

Answer (score 0):

Достаточно выполнить команду:

```
git push -u origin
```

И если с авторизацией всё в порядке на сервере создастся ваша ветка.

Comment: увы, всё та же ошибка

Comment: А вообще удаленный сервер указан? Выдает что-то `git remote -v`?

Comment: спасбо, уже разобрался)
_git push origin nojira_fix_telegram_bot_

Answer (score 0):

`git branch --set-upstream nojira_fix_telegram_bot origin/nojira_fix_telegram_bot`

Answer (score 0):

Вот решение

```
git push origin nojira_fix_telegram_bot
```